# grails 2.5.x does not evict oldest version of conflicting library

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-2.0

Using grails 2.5.1 with, in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
[...]
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
[...]
```

I have a grails application including 2 custom plugins (hosted on our nexus maven repo): `gw-mr:1.7.3-RELEASE` and `gw-mr-security:1.7.4-RELEASE`

These 2 plugins depend on the same library, `mr-client`. However `gw-mr` lags behind `gw-mr-security` and was not rebuilt for some time, but its code has not changed. In the meantime, `gw-mr-security` has been bumped, and uses a newer version of the common library: `mr-client`. So if we take a look at the POM of `gw-mr`:

```
[...]
<dependency>
<groupId>irrelevant</groupId>
<artifactId>mr-client</artifactId>
<version>3.6.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
[...]
```

And looking at the POM of `gw-mr-security`, we see:

```
[...]
<dependency>
<groupId>irrelevant</groupId>
<artifactId>mr-client</artifactId>
<version>3.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
[...]
```

So, indeed, `gw-mr-security` declares a later version of `mr-client` than `gw-mr`.

When I include these 2 plugins in the host grails application, I can see something really weird, when I run `grails dependency-report compile`:

```
[...]
+--- irrelevant:gw-mr:1.7.3-RELEASE
|    \--- irrelevant:mr-client:3.6.5-20170921.151252-2
+--- irrelevant:gw-mr-security:1.7.4-RELEASE
+--- irrelevant:gw-rest:1.7.8-RELEASE
[...]
```

So, even though my app declares both plugins in its dependencies (BuildConfig.groovy):

```
[...]
compile "irrelevant:gw-mr:1.7.3-RELEASE"
compile "irrelevant:gw-mr-security:1.7.4-RELEASE"
[...]
```

grails still does not examine both transitive dependencies and evicts the dependency coming from `gw-mr` (`3.6.5-SNAPSHOT`) for more recent version included in `gw-mr-security` (`3.9.0-SNAPSHOT`).

Of course, when I include the transitive dependency explicitly in my host application:

```
[...]
compile "irrelevant:mr-client:3.9.0-SNAPSHOT"
[...]
```

Then the right library is packaged in my war.

Is my assumption wrong, that grails evicts older versions of the transitive dependencies included by plugins?

Thanks for any insight.